# Trigger to invalidate cache after update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger to invalidate the word index for my story database. However I can't seem to figure out how to stop the trigger from firing again during the indexing operation. I know I need to place an if statement to stop the update, but I can't seem to figure out what it should look like.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trMarkStoryForReindex BEFORE UPDATE ON Chapters
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    -- any update to any chapter invalidates the index for the whole story
    -- we could just periodically flush the story index, but this way is
    -- better.
    SET New.isIndexed = FALSE;
    -- delete the index for that story
    -- It will get rebuilt in at most 15 minutes
    DELETE FROM freq WHERE storyid = NEW.StoryId;
END;
```

I basically want the trigger to fire only when isIndexed is has not been set in the update statement causing the trigger.

My data model looks like so:

Chapters

- id
- isIndexed
- StoryId

Freq

- word
- storyid

Comment: There's no `StoryId` field in your `Chapters` table. Do you mean: `delete from freq where storyid = new.id`?

Comment: @Barranka There is a StoryId field in the chapters table. I just forgot to include that in the question.

Comment: Could you please post a data sample, or an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposal for solution. I've tested this on SQL fiddle, and it seems to work:

```
-- Database setup
create table chapters (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  isIndexed boolean default false,
  storyId int not null,
  index idx_storyId(storyId)
);

create table freq (
  word varchar(50),
  storyId int not null,
  index idx_storyId(storyId)
);

delimiter //
create trigger bi_chapters before update on chapters
for each row
begin
  if new.isIndexed = false then
    delete from freq where storyId = new.storyId;
  end if;
end //
delimiter ;

insert into freq(word, storyId) 
values ('one', 1), ('two', 1), ('three', 2);

insert into chapters(isIndexed, storyId) 
values (true, 1), (true, 2);
```

When you select the values from `freq` (before updating `chapters`) you get this:

```
select * from chapters;

| id | isIndexed | storyId |
|----|-----------|---------|
|  1 |     false |       1 |
|  2 |      true |       2 |

select * from freq;

|  word | storyId |
|-------|---------|
|   one |       1 |
|   two |       1 |
| three |       2 |
```

Now, do an `update` to chapters and `select` from `freq` again:

```
update chapters
  set isIndexed = false
  where storyId = 1;
select * from freq;

|  word | storyId |
|-------|---------|
| three |       2 |
```

The only modification I did is that `if` block that checks if the new row is updated to `false`. If I've understood your question correctly, this would do what you need.

- [SQL fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22444/2)